# "You are not currently attached to a supported page or app." error while executing JQuery code in Internet Explorer 11 console

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, console, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to execute following code in IE 11 Console:

```
var alinks = $('a');
for (var i = 0; i < alinks.length; i++) {
    if ($(alinks[i]).text().trim() == "Contact Management") {
          alinks[i].click();
          break;
    }
}
```

But I am getting following error:

> You are not currently attached to a supported page or app.

I researched on Google and SO but didn't find any solutions or reasons for this error.

I also tried running this code in Chrome and Firefox and it's working fine there.

**UPDATE**

I also tried simple `console.log('s')` but it's showing `undefined` without display `s`. Also, no alert when `alert('s')` is executed.

Comment: Assuming you're running this through the IE dev tools console, then it sounds like a security feature. Was the process launched from a Visual Studio instance?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No, I just opened up IE manually and executed the code.

Comment: Almost sounds like there is some way to disable running code in console in IE from parent page. Just a guess though. Never heard of that feature other than overloading the `console` object itself

Comment: @charlietfl So is there any workaround?

Comment: Oh I have no idea. First time I ever heard of this error and was only guessing. I don't spend much time worrying about IE these days like was critical years ago where everything you did needed some sort of IE hack

Answer (score 5):

Go to Tools> Internet Options > Security > Tap on Custom Level button > Under Scripting, Enable Active Scripting > Ok

[image: Sample Image]

Restart internet Explorer

Hoe it works :)